Combine Table and Plot using ggplot and gridExtra
Trying to find a more elegant solution for combining plots with tables using dplyr, ggplot, and gridExtra package.  Addtionally, need help controlling digits displayed in table.
I would like to do the following without taking my table to a data.frame:
library("tidyverse")
library("gridExtra")

# data
ddd<-bind_cols(runif(5,0,1),(runif(5,0,1))) |>
  set_names(c("yo","hi"))

# format digits and get as Grob  NEED HELP WITH THIS STEP!
t <- as.data.frame(ddd)
t <- format(t, digits=1)
t <- tableGrob(t)

# plot
p<- ggplot(data=ddd)+
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x=yo,y=hi))

# my go to gridExtra
lay<-rbind(c(1,2))

grid.arrange(p,t, layout_matrix=lay)


The ggpp package offers a nice solution for adding a table to a plot.
The x and y in tbl_df control the position of the table tb when added as a plot layer.
across(everything(), \(x) round(x, 1)) is rounding all columns to 1 dec place for the table only.
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpp)

set.seed(1)
ddd <- tibble(yo = runif(5, 0, 1), hi = runif(5, 0, 1))

ddd2 <- ddd |> mutate(across(everything(), \(x) round(x, 1)))

tbl_df <- tibble(x = 0.25, y = 0.95, tb = list(ddd2))

ggplot(ddd) +
  geom_table(aes(x, y, label = tb), data = tbl_df) +
  geom_point(aes(yo, hi))


Created on 2024-04-05 with reprex v2.1.0

Elegance is in the eye of the beholder. For the most control possible, I would tend to construct the table as a ggplot rather than as a grob, since it gives a great deal more freedom for customization.
p <- ggplot(ddd, aes(yo, hi)) + geom_point()

t <- ddd %>% 
  rownames_to_column() %>%
  mutate(rowname = as.numeric(rowname)) %>%
  pivot_longer(-1) %>%
  mutate(value = format(round(value, 1))) %>%
  add_row(rowname = 0, name = 'yo', value = 'yo') %>%
  add_row(rowname = 0, name = 'hi', value = 'hi') %>%
  ggplot(aes(name, 5 - rowname)) +
  geom_tile(color = 'white', linewidth = 0.5,
            aes(fill = factor(ifelse(rowname == 0, 5, rowname %% 2)))) +
  geom_text(aes(label = value)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('#e5e5e5', '#f2f2f2', '#cccccc'), 
                    guide = 'none') +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(1, 1)) +
  theme_void()

grid.arrange(p, t, layout_matrix = rbind(c(1, 2)))


